# Making bootstrap columns nested in rows take full screen height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have some code for a project I'm making and I'm having trouble on the bootstrap layout. I want to make these columns add up to be the  full screen height. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8h57tcvL/) is a jsfiddle of what I have now. I have all the rows nested in the columns set to

```
height:100%
```

because this was the closest I could get to what I want. I want to make something that looks like this (excuse my poor MS paint drawing skills):
[image]

Here is my code in case the link doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Link to css file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/main.css" mesdia="screen"/>

<!-- Bootstrap CDN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Layout</title>
<!--<h1>Welcome to the layout</h1>
<p>Where would you like to navigate to?</p>-->
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" id="navcols">

    <div class="col layoutcol">
        <div class="row layoutrow" id="LeftCol1">Row</div>
        <div class="row layoutrow" id="LeftCol2">Row</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 layoutcol">
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col layoutcol">
        <div class="row layoutrow" id="RightCol">Row</div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>

<!--
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 id="test">Welcome to my page! Where do you want to navigate to?</h1>
</div>-->
```

And here is the CSS

```
html,body {
height: 100%;
```

width: 100%;
    }

```
.col {
background-color:lime;
}

#LeftCol1 {
background-color:blue;
height: 100%;
}

#LeftCol2 {
background-color:red;
height: 100%
}

.layoutrow{
border:solid 1px black;
}

.MidCol{
height: 100%;
}

#RightCol {
height: 100%;
}
```

How can I go about making this change? Thanks!

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry! That has been fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeking can be possible with css and bootstrap combination.
Here What I have done.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Grid </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .first .first_row{
      background-color: #ff0000;
      height: 50vh;
      border:2px solid black;
    }
    .first .second_row{
      background-color: #ffff00;
      height: 50vh;
      border:2px solid black;
    }

    .second .first_row{
      background-color: #cc99ff;
      height: 20vh;
      border:2px solid black;
    }
    .second .second_row{
      background-color: #ff0066;
      height: 20vh;
      border:2px solid black;
    }
    .second .third_row{
      background-color: #0099ff;
      height: 20vh;
      border:2px solid black;
    }
    .second .fourth_row{
      background-color: #006666;
      height: 20vh;
      border:2px solid black;
    }
    .second .fifth_row{
      background-color: #000099;
      height: 20vh;
      border:2px solid black;
    }
    .third .first_row{
      background-color: #006600;
      height: 100vh;
      border:2px solid black;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 first">
        <div class="row first_row">
        </div>
        <div class="row second_row">
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 second">
        <div class="row first_row">
        </div>
        <div class="row second_row">
        </div>
        <div class="row third_row">
        </div>
        <div class="row fourth_row">
        </div>
        <div class="row fifth_row">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 third">
        <div class="row first_row">
        </div>    
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it will help you.
P.S. Don't mind the colors.

Comment: My pleasure to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the inner rows inside a container like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 layoutcol">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
        <div class="row MidCol layoutrow">Row</div>
    </div>
</div>
```